# Use woocommerce_product_thumbnails hook to go up?

Tags: woocommerce, product

In Wordpress and Woocommerce, I would like to use javascript within the child theme functions.php, so if a user clicks on a product alternatigve images it goes up to top of the page.
But does woocommerce_product_thumbnails has been deprecated ?
Thanks.

Comment: With js you target element and from there on click something to happen. What has to do with woocommerce_product_thumbnails  ?

Comment: right! finaly I don't care to use woocommerce_product_thumbnails or not as I just need to name clearly to element to click on.

Comment: I tried something like that, but nothing happened...
function action_clic() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $( '.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper' ).transitionend( function() {
             window.location.href = '#main-content';
             return false;
         } );

    </script>
<?php }; 
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_clic');

Comment: Solution that works .
function ajouter_script_personnalise() {
    if (is_product()) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('.woocommerce-product-gallery').on('click', 'img', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'ajouter_script_personnalise');